# Show that the minimal polynomial of $T:\mathbb{K}^n \mapsto \mathbb{K}^n$ remains the same over field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Show that the minimal polynomial of linear transformation $T:\mathbb{K}^n \mapsto \mathbb{K}^n$ remains the same over field extension using the cyclic decomposition theorem.

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a field and let $\mathbb{K}$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Then we see that the minimal polynomial of $T$ over $\mathbb{K}$ (say $p_K(x)$) divides the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$(say $p_C(x)$)

Now assume that $p_C(x)= (x-c_1)p_K(x)$

I don't understand where do I use the cyclic decomposition theorem.Some hints rather than the  complete answer would be helpful

Edit 1:
Here's my attempt to the outline given in the answer:

We try to show that $p_{\mathbb{C}}(x) | p_{\mathbb{K}}(x)$.

Now $p_{\mathbb{K}}(T)(e_i) = 0, 1 \le i \le n$ . [ As $e_i \in \mathbb{K}^n , \forall i   s.t. 1 \le i \le n]$

Now $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ then $v = d_1.e_1 + \cdots + d_n.e_n$ where $d_i \in \mathbb{C}$ then $p_{\mathbb{K}}(T)(d_1.e_1 + \cdots d_n.e_n) = p_{\mathbb{K}}(T)(d_1.e_1) + \cdots + p_{\mathbb{K}}(T)(d_n.e_n) $ then $p_{\mathbb{K}}(T)(v) = 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}$.

Then by the definition of minimal polynomial we see that $p_{\mathbb{C}}(x) | p_{\mathbb{K}}(x)$.

Now to show the converse we know that by the cyclic decomposition theorem we can write :

$\mathbb{K}^n = Z(\alpha_1;T) \bigoplus \cdots \bigoplus Z(\alpha_k;T)$

Then $T_{Z(\alpha_i;T)} = T|_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$ then as $Z(\alpha_i;T)$ is a cyclic subspace then we know that the minimal polynomial of $T_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$ is the same as the c.p. of $T_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$.

Now the c.p.($T$) = m.p.($T_{Z(\alpha_1;T)}$).mp.($T_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$).... m.p.($T_{Z(\alpha_j;T)}$

Also the minimal polynomial of $T$ over $\mathbb{K}$ is the l.c.m.( m.p.($T_{Z(\alpha_1;T)}$),mp.($T_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$),...., m.p.($T_{Z(\alpha_j;T)})$

Thus $p_{\mathbb{K}}(x) = $ l.c.m.( m.p.($T_{Z(\alpha_1;T)}$),mp.($T_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$),...., m.p.($T_{Z(\alpha_j;T)})$

Now by the definition of the characteristic polynomial of $T$ it remains the same over any field.

Now $p_{\mathbb{C}}(x) | $ c.p.$(x)$ then by the property of the l.c.m. we can claim that $p_{\mathbb{K}}(x) | p_{\mathbb{C}}(x)$

Hence $p_{\mathbb{K}}(x) = p_{\mathbb{C}}(x)$.

Comment: How exactly do you "see" that the minimal polynomial over $\Bbb K$ divides the minimal polynomial over $\Bbb C$? If anything, I would say that $p_{\Bbb C} \mid p_{\Bbb K}$ is the easier conclusion to reach.

Comment: In $\mathbb{K}^n$ every $v'=c_1.e_1+ \cdots c_n.e_n$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{K}$ ,$p_C(T)(\sum_{i=1}^n d_i.e_i)=0$ where $d_i \in \mathbb{C}$ so shouldn't it imply that $p_C(T)v'=0$? I am not sure how should I start?

Comment: Yes, it is true that $p_{\Bbb C}(T)v' = 0$ for all $v' \in \Bbb K^n$, and if we know that $p_{\Bbb C}$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb K$, then that is enough to conclude that $p_{\Bbb K} \mid p_{\Bbb C}$ by the definition of the minimal polynomial. However, we cannot assume without proof that $p_{\Bbb C}$ has coefficients from the subfield $\Bbb K$.

Comment: Okay so how do I proceed?

Comment: By the way, please edit your post to include a statement of what $T$ is. For example, you could edit your question to state "Show that the minimal polynomial of **a linear transformation $T:\Bbb K^n \to \Bbb K^n$** remains the same over field extension using the cyclic decomposition theorem."

Comment: $p_{\mathbb{C}}$ has coefficients from the subfield $\mathbb{K}$ . $\mathbb{K}$ can vary so the coefficients of the minimal polynomial is from the smallest subfield inside $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Why does $p_{\Bbb C}$ have coefficients from the subfield $\Bbb K$? What do you mean by "$\Bbb K$ can vary"? It is not true that **every** transformation over $\Bbb C$ has a minimal polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb K$, so I don't understand your argument.

Comment: By the way, your usage of $\mapsto$ (`\mapsto`)  instead of $\to$ (`\to`) is strange. Typically, $f:A \to B$ means that $f$ is a function from its domain $A$ to its codomain $B$, where as $f:x \mapsto y$ means that $f$ is a function for which $f(x) = y$, so that $x$ is an *element of* the domain and $y$ is an element of the codomain.

Comment: @BenGrossman If you have time can you go through this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348386/show-that-the-rational-form-of-a-remains-the-same-whether-viewed-as-a-matrix-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline of solution:** One approach is to show that $p_{\Bbb C} = p_{\Bbb K}$ by showing that $p_{\Bbb C} \mid p_{\Bbb K}$ and $p_{\Bbb K} \mid p_{\Bbb C}$, where $p \mid q$ means "$p$ divides $q$".

The easy direction of the proof is showing that $p_{\Bbb C} \mid p_{\Bbb K}$. Argue that $p_{\Bbb K}(T) v = 0$ for all $v \in \Bbb C^n$, then apply the definition of the characteristic polynomial.

One way to show that $p_{\Bbb K} \mid p_{\Bbb C}$ is to cyclic decomposition theorem (CDT). First, note that by the CDT, it suffices to consider a transformation $T$ for which $\Bbb K^n$ is a cyclic subspace. Then, note that for such a transformation, the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $T$ (over a given field) are the same. Finally, using the definition of the characteristic polynomial, argue that $T$ and its extension to a map over $\Bbb C^n$ have the same characteristic polynomials.

Comment: By the cdt we can write $\mathbb{K}^n = Z(v_1;T)  \bigoplus  \cdots  \bigoplus Z(v_k;T)$. I don't understand what does it mean to "consider a T for which $\mathbb{K}^n$" is cyclic?

Comment: @Antimony In other words, it suffices to consider the restrictions $T|_{Z(v_j;T)}$. The space $Z(v_j;T)$ on which this restricted map acts is $T|_{Z(v_j;T)}$-cyclic.

Comment: Can you go through my edit?

Comment: Looked through, your proof looks fine

Comment: I have got a doubt over here.The way that I have shown that $p_C | p_k$ is it possible to show the converse in the same way ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am confused at the same place, that why we are not using similar argument like $p_C \mid p_K$. My claim is, we know $p_K(T)(u)=0, \ \forall u\in \mathbb{K}^n$. Now since $\mathbb{C}^n$ is an extension then $\mathbb{K}^n$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}^n$  with same identity and $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}^n$. Hence $u\in \mathbb{C}^n \implies p_C(T)(u)=0, \forall u\in \mathbb{K}^n$.  Now, the minimal polynomial of $T:\mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ is $p_K$ and  $p_C(T)(u)=0, \forall u\in \mathbb{K}^n$, then $p_K \mid p_C$.

Comment: @Shankhadeep The problem is that $p_C$ might be a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb C$ rather than $\Bbb K$. The fact that $p_K$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ only ensures that for a polynomial $p$ **with coefficients in $\Bbb K$**, if $p(T) = 0$ then $p_K \mid p$.

Comment: @Antimony See my comment above