# Show that the rational form of $A$ remains the same whether viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ or over $\mathbb{F}$(subfield)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> **Question:** Let $\Bbb F$ be a subfield of $\Bbb C$ (the complex numbers), and let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are similar over $\Bbb C$, then they are similar over $\Bbb F$. (*Hint:* Prove that the rational form of $A$ is the same whether viewed as a matrix over $\Bbb F$ or a matrix over $\Bbb C$, likewise for $B$).

I am working on the hint given above. I don't have any intuition as to how to start the problem.

$\mathbb{F}^n = Z(\alpha_1;T) \bigoplus \cdots \bigoplus Z(\alpha_k;T)$

Also $p_{i+1}|p_i$ where $p_i$ is the T annihilator of $\alpha_i$.

Where $p_1$ is the minimal polynomial of T(which remains the same over field extension)

Edit 1:This question is form Hoffman and kunze . The question is to show that if two matrices are similar over $\mathbb{C}$ then they are similar over $\mathbb{F}$(subfield).The hint given in the book is that " Show that the rational form of $A$ remains the same whether viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ or over $\mathbb{F}$(subfield)"

This is what I know.Any hints to start the problem would be helpful.

Comment: One approach is to note that $p_i$ is the minimal polynomial of the restriction $T|_{Z(\alpha_1;T) \oplus \cdots \oplus Z(\alpha_i;T)}$ and proceed "backwards"

Comment: What do I have to show that if I have $\mathbb{C}^n$ then the cyclic decomposition of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ is same?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I was not able to see through the problem. Could you help me out a bit more

Comment: I realize I made a mistake with my comment. I meant to say that $p_i$ is the minimal polynomial of $T|_{Z(\alpha_i;T)\oplus \cdots \oplus Z(\alpha_k;T)}$ is $p_i$.

Comment: I'll give a longer explanation if I find the time

Comment: Assume that $\mathbb{C}^n =Z(\beta_1;T) +\bigoplus ... +\bigoplus Z(\beta_r;T)$ then do we need to show that $r=k$ and if $g_i$ is the annihilator of $\beta_i$ then $g_i=p_i$?

Comment: An alternative approach is to notice  that the set of $p_i$ is determined by the set of highest common factors of the $r\times r$ minors of $A-xI$ : and this set is calculated in the ring of polynomials over the smallest field containing the entries of $A$.  [Smith Normal Form etc etc]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Well I don't what is Smith normal form. I really didn't understand the approach.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be quickly answered with an approach framed by the following result.

> **HK Section 7.2, Theorem 5:** Let $\Bbb F$ be a field and let $B$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over $\Bbb F$. Then $B$ is similar over the field $\Bbb F$ to one and only one matrix which is in rational form.

Now, let $A$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix with elements in $\Bbb F$ (i.e. $A \in \Bbb F^{n \times n}$). We know from the theorem that there exist matrices $C,P \in \Bbb F^{n \times n}$ such that $C$ is in rational canonical form, $P$ is invertible, and
$$
A = P^{-1}CP.
$$
It follows that when $A,C,P$ are considered as elements of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$, we still have $A = P^{-1}CP$. However, $C$ is in rational canonical form. By theorem 5, this means that $C$ is the rational canonical form of $A$, as a matrix in $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$.

The conclusion follows.

---

We are given that $\Bbb F$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C$. For any vector space $V$ over $\Bbb F$, I will use $\bar V$ to refer to the extension of $V$ to a vector space over $\Bbb C$. In your setting, we have $V \subset \Bbb F^n \subset \Bbb C^n$, so we can more simply say that $\bar V = \{z v : z \in \Bbb C, v \in V\}$. In a more general setting, we might say that $\bar V = V \otimes_{\Bbb F} \Bbb C$ is obtained via an [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars).

Let $T$ denote the linear map $T:\Bbb F^n \to \Bbb F^n$ given by $T(x) = Ax$. In a similar vein, I will use $\bar T$ to refer to the map induced by $T$ on $\Bbb C^n$, whereas $T$ refers to a map on $\Bbb F^n$. More generally: for a $\Bbb F$-linear map $\tau:V \to V$, $\bar \tau$ denotes the induced $\Bbb C$-linear map $\bar \tau : \bar V \to \bar V$

I claim (without proof) that the the following holds:

1. If $V = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_k$, then $\bar V = \bar V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \bar V_k$
2. $\overline{Z_{\Bbb F}(\alpha,T)} = Z_{\Bbb C}(\alpha,\bar T)$.

The subscripts here emphasize $Z(\alpha,T) = Z_{\Bbb F}(\alpha,T)$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F$, whereas $Z(\alpha,\bar T) = Z_{\Bbb C}(\alpha,\bar T)$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$.

We are given that $\Bbb F^n$ has the $T$-cyclic decomposition
$$
\Bbb F^n = Z(\alpha_1;T) \oplus \cdots \oplus Z(\alpha_k;T)
$$
where $p_{i+1}\mid p_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,k-1$. The question asks us to show that $\bar T$ has the same canonical form as $T$. To do this, it suffices to show that $\Bbb C^n$ has the $\bar T$-cyclic decomposition
$$
\Bbb C^n = Z(\alpha_1;\bar T)\oplus \cdots \oplus Z(\alpha_k;\bar T)
$$
and that the $\bar T$-annihilator of $\alpha_i$ is $p_i$ for each $i$.

First of all, using statements 1 and 2, we have
$$
\Bbb C^n = \overline{\Bbb F^n} = \overline{Z(\alpha_1;T) \oplus \cdots \oplus Z(\alpha_k;T)} = 
Z(\alpha_1;\bar T)\oplus \cdots \oplus Z(\alpha_k;\bar T).
$$
Now, it suffices to show that for each $i$, the $\bar T$-annihilator of $\alpha_i$ is equal to $p_i$, the $T$-annihilator of $\alpha_i$. To show that this holds, note that the $T$-annihilator of $\alpha_i$ is the characteristic/minimal polynomial of $T|_{Z(\alpha_i;T)}$. From your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4347738/81360), we know that $\overline{T|_{Z(\alpha_i; T)}}$ has the same characteristic and minimal polynomials as $T|_{Z(\alpha_i; T)}$. However,
$$
\overline{T|_{Z(\alpha_i; T)}} = \bar T|_{\overline{Z(\alpha_i;T)}} = 
\bar T|_{Z(\alpha_i;\bar T)},
$$
which means that the $\bar T$-annihilator of $\alpha_i$ is equal to the minimal polynomial of $\bar T|_{Z(\alpha_i;\bar T)}$, which is equal to the minimal polynomial of $T|_{Z(\alpha_i; T)}$, which is equal to $p_i$.

The conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but how do I show the claims (1) and (2)?

Comment: @Antimony It is straightforward to do this from the definition I've given and the definition of $Z(\alpha;T)$

Comment: @Antimony It would be helpful if you edit your post to include the context in which you found this question so that instead of introducing you to new definitions, we can use the tools that you are expected to be comfortable with.

Comment: I did edit the question

Comment: @Antimony The context you have now provided is very important, and is something that you should provide by default going forward. First, it was not clear that $\Bbb C$ referred specifically to the complex numbers in this context. Second, I strongly suspect that there are other exercises in this section that make this question easier. By the way, your question would have been clearer if you had copied the question word for word instead of trying to shorten it.

Comment: @Antimony Notice that an important detail that H+K include in their questions (which you have consistently omitted) is "let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices". Perhaps the fact that $A$ is a matrix is obvious to you from the context, but it is helpful to explicitly state the "type" of each object that is referenced in the question.

Comment: @Antimony To add to my first recent comment, there could also be theorems given in the book that address my statements that I didn't prove. Again, it is useful to know what tools you have at hand.

Comment: @Antimony See my latest edit.